# Facebook's persistent menu postback not hitting controller

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger

Using C#, Microsoft.Bot.Builder 3.5.5

The chatbot works just fine, but when a button postback is selected from the persistent menu, the chatbot shows the typing animation for 20~ seconds before failing with no message. Typing the exact message works fine, in fact any message should have a response. 
I also looked into the channel issues at dev.botframework.com and nothing related to it shows up.

Edit: I'm not even using any logic to show a typing message. It only shows up for the menu.

Comment: Are you able to post your code so we can take a look friend?

Comment: Well, it's not even reaching my code. It's not even entering in `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)`

Unless you mean my persistent menu. I've copied and pasted the one from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/persistent-menu) and it succeeds, the bot just doesn't respond to postbacks from the menu.

Comment: This happens with me on NodeJS as well, it doesn't even reach the first middleware (the request to the server isn't even made at all). But "sometimes" it works :S

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that when you created persistent menu, you've made request to Facebook similar to this :

```
{
  "persistent_menu":[
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "composer_input_disabled":true,
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title":"My Account",
          "type":"nested",
          "call_to_actions":[
            {
              "title":"Pay Bill",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"PAYBILL_PAYLOAD"
            },
            {
              "title":"History",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"HISTORY_PAYLOAD"
            },
            {
              "title":"Contact Info",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"CONTACT_INFO_PAYLOAD"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type":"web_url",
          "title":"Latest News",
          "url":"http://petershats.parseapp.com/hat-news",
          "webview_height_ratio":"full"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "locale":"zh_CN",
      "composer_input_disabled":false
    }
  ]
}
```

I got this Json from official [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/persistent-menu).

So, when user hits any item of this persistent menu with `"type":"postback"`, your received message.Text is equal to defined `payload`.

Your code for handling postback should be something like this :

```
 private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {

        var msg = await argument;
        switch (s)
          {
            case "CONTACT_INFO_PAYLOAD" : 
            YourMethod();
            break;
          }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is before I send them down a dialog, it should hit our controller, but it's not so I'm not even getting the activity to even seen what activity.Text is. Messages outside of the persistent menu are all working fine and hitting our controller. I can create my own Facebook buttons inside the bot with their own payload and everything works fine, just not the persistent menu.

Comment: Update your bot version ? Report this to Facebook ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using suggested action instead of the persistent menu.  You can find information about [suggested actions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-suggested-actions) You should also upgrade to the latest version of botbuilder 3.8.1

Here is a simple implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

namespace SuggestedActions.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;
            var reply = activity.CreateReply("I have colors in mind, but need your help to choose the best one.");
            reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
            reply.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Plain;
            reply.SuggestedActions = new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.SuggestedActions()
            {
                Actions = new List<CardAction>()
                {
                    new CardAction(){ Title = "Blue", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="Blue" },
                    new CardAction(){ Title = "Red", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="Red" },
                    new CardAction(){ Title = "Green", Type=ActionTypes.ImBack, Value="Green" }
                }
            };
            // return our reply to the user
            await context.PostAsync(reply);
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
}
```